# How to apply one pose after another via scripting?

Tags: scripting, armature, bones, transforms, pose-mode

I have 3 poses: `Default` , `Location` , `Rotate` & I need to execute them in that order, like this:

```
armature.pose = armature.pose["Default"]; #1
armature.pose = armature.pose["Location"]; #2
armature.pose = armature.pose["Rotate"]; #3
```

but this does not work, instead whatever pose was selected manually before running the script it seems to be going from it to `Rotate`

For example if `Default` was selected manually and then the script was run, this is the pattern it follows:

`Default` -> `Default`
`Default` -> `Location`
`Default` -> `Rotate`

> The output of this is that it shows only rotation change

Whereas it should be:

`Default` -> `Default`
`Default` -> `Location`
`Location` -> `Rotate`

> The output of this should be that it changes location then rotates

Comment: What do you mean by 'execute'? Poses are static positions.  Are you trying to generate an animation where Blender uses interpolation to move from one pose to another over many frames?  You need to move to a frame, set the pose, keyframe the pose, and then move to a later frame and do the same thing with the next pose.

Answer (score 0):

I may have come up with a pseudo solution:

```
armature.pose = armature.pose["Default"]; #1
bpy.ops.screen.animation_play();
armature.pose = armature.pose["Location"]; #2
bpy.ops.screen.animation_play();
armature.pose = armature.pose["Rotate"]; #3
```

but I'm not sure if it will work everytime